# In my case $inc modifier isn't concurrent mongodb? Is there something that I can do to make it concurrent?

Tags: mongodb

I'm having a simple $inc that has also `{upsert: true}`. Meaning that it is supposed to create it if it doesn't exist.

I'm having daily more a than a million of such calls a day. It usually works ok. But from time to time I see that there were two documents created with the same parameters. Meaning that there is a problem with concurrency.

Is there something that I can do to make it concurrent?

According to the following stackoverflow answer it is supposed to be concurrent.
[How does the $inc modifier work with concurrent requests in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025278/how-does-the-inc-modifier-work-with-concurrent-requests-in-mongodb)

The problem is that it isn't by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `$inc` is atomic, an upsert is not atomic when a document needs to be inserted.

So what you need to do is add a unique index to your collection that covers the fields you're upserting by and then handle the duplicate key exception to recover from unintended duplicates.

An example of this from [this other answer on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295648/mongoose-duplicate-key-error-with-upsert/37485551#37485551):

```
var minute = utils.minute();
Monitor.update({ _id: minute }, { $inc: update }, { upsert: true }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 11000) {
            // Another upsert occurred during the upsert, try again. You could omit the
            // upsert option here if you don't ever delete docs while this is running.
            Monitor.update({ _id: minute }, { $inc: update }, { upsert: true },
                function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.trace(err);
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            console.trace(err);
        }
    }
});
```